# JUnit multiple transaction managers for spring tests

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, junit

I'm using Spring 3.0.5 and Junit 4.8.2
Is it possible to use multiple transaction managers during tests?

Basically I'm try for something like this. I need to add and remove content from two separate databases during the tests.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml" })
    @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txMgrA", defaultRollback = true)
    @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txMgrB", defaultRollback = true)
    @Transactional 
public class SampleTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unrelated point: why not use `classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml` instead of `file:...`?  It gets copied to target/test-classes, right?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at Spring 5 `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` implementation, it looks it only supports one `TransactionManager` **per thread**, what seems to be a design flaw of this listener, probably the same as you came across in 2011 :)

However, currently it's possible to workaround this using `ChainedTransactionManager`. If you have multiple transaction managers, you can define yet another transaction manager in your test context:

```
@Configuration
class TestTransactionConfig {

    @Bean("testTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("transactionManager1") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager1,
        @Qualifier("transactionManager2") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2
    ) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(transactionManager1, transactionManager2);
    }

}
```

Now, you can define your base class for tests using this transaction manager:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@Transactional("testTransactionManager")
class BaseTransactionalTest {

}
```

For all derived classes all test methods will now be wrapped in both transactions, which will be finally rolled back by `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.

Answer (score 5):

Since Java will not allow multiple annotations of the same type per element, you must find another way to configure it.  `@TransactionConfiguration` is interpreted by [`TransactionalTestExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html), whose  [`getTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html#getTransactionManager%28org.springframework.test.context.TestContext%29) method only returns a single PlatformTransactionManager.  It looks at @Transactional but seems to ignore the `value` qualifier that was added in Seam 3.0.

@Transactional itself only supports a single transaction manager.  How is the real application configured? You must be using `@Transactional("<qualifier>")` (as in [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional)), right?

If you just use @Transactional with different tx managers on different methods, then the simplest solution is to just split your test class.

Are you nesting the transactions?  That is, you have @Transactional("tm1") on one method, which calls a nested method that has @Transactional("tm2")?  Sounds a little unusual.  You could try to set up your test in the same way -- have two test @Services, each with the appropriate @Transactional annotations, that are proxied with tx:advice as usual.  The outer service sets up the outer txn; the inner service sets up the inner txn and contains the actual test code.  You can't use @Rollback, but hey, hacks ain't pretty.

Another option would be to create your own PlatformTransactionManager that delegates to the two other managers (for testing purposes only).

Maybe better would be to just give up and manually manage the two transactions in the test's @Before/@After methods.

Best would be to use JTA global transactions.  Hopefully you're not actually nesting separate transactions and this is all moot ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions Peter, but sadly none of them worked. When nesting the transactions, only the transactions performed on the inner method are rolled back. We might resort to manually managing the the transaction using the @Before/@After methods (but that's something I'm trying to avoid).